Is there a MSVC warning for using 0 instead of nullptr?
GCC and Clang have -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant to flag the legacy use of 0 instead of nullptr. Does MSVC have a similar warning?

Does warning C4965 work for your purposes?

@Eljay:  It looks like that warning is specific to MSVC's extensions for "managed" C++.  I assume the question is about "native" C++.

@AdrianMcCarthy • aww, drat.  Their summary list for C++ warnings didn't distinguish the C++/CX specific warnings.  I wish they wouldn't commingled their not C++ warnings (i.e, C++/CX) in with the C++ warnings, on their summary list of C++ warnings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26477?view=msvc-170

Warning C26477 requires Core Guidlines checker to be run, see /analyze https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=msvc-170

@AdrianMcCarthy, yes, if it weren’t a native C++ question, I’d have used the relevant tags.
